# Android and gradle uses old non-existing keystore when signing app

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I tried to sign my new android app using data from some old keystore named **"keystore.keystore"**. It couldn't recover key so I deleted that keystore from disk and created a new one, named **"keystore.jks"**.

Then I added the following to build.gradle, following guide from page https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#signing:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("C:\\SomeDirectory\\keystore.jks")
        storePassword "mypassword123"
        keyAlias "key"
        keyPassword "mypassword123"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Then I went to **Build / Generate Signed Bundle/APK** menu option in Android Studio. It didn't pick information about keystore, key or alias from the above build.gradle file, so I entered it again manually in the dialog window.

After pressing Next, the task completed with the following error:

> "C:\SomeDirectory\keystore.keystore (The system cannot find the file
>   specified)".

Notice the name of the keystore, it's the old name. Where does it come from???

So I opened cmd.exe and ran this: "gradlew.bat assembleRelease". There was similar error:

> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\SomeDirectory\keystore.keystore
>    (The system cannot find the file specified)

Invalidating caches/restarting doesn't help.

Why is gradle referring to the old keystore name, how to make it use the new keystore?

Comment: Nope, it outputs the same error.

Answer (score 3):

`gradlew clean` will make gradle use the new one

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! Your answer is quite short and has more the character of a comment. Please read our guide How to write a good answer and try to improve yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue today.

What worked for me was to delete the `app/build/intermediates/signing_config/release/out/signing-config.json` file between builds (I don't know why this works).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MAC ~/Users/[username]/.gradle/gradle.properties should be edited also

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. A Android Studio Clean Project and Reboot solve it for me.